# android: google mapview IOException

Tags: android

I am building an app that uses mapview. With one MapActivity, everything works fine. But when i add another MapActivity that uses a different xml containing mapview (but same map key), both the maps stop working and throw IOExceptions

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

When run on emulator, Log simply displays

```
05-02 19:56:05.975: INFO/Mapcoordinates(398): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
```

I am using two mapactivities that use two different map views but with same key

the app requires map on two activities

Comment: Post your logcat output please

Comment: I guess, You can't have two MapActivities in single projects.

Comment: Do you have two separate class/MapActivites? You only need one MapActivity and one mapview xml.. Why do you have two? You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: According to the API "Only one MapActivity is supported per process". This does not necessarily mean per application. (An application may have separate processes, see http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html)

Comment: can you pls suggest how to use 2 maps then?

Comment: You can put each activity in its own process using the android:process attribute in the manifest. I have no experience of this, as I've never found it necessary for my apps.

Comment: K thanks.. will try that and post the results here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [NickT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440010/nickt), I came to know that i cant have two mapviews under the name process. But having every activity in a different process seemed a risky thing to me. So here's my workaround:

1. Create a common layout xml for the two map activities that contains components used by both.
2. In your custom implementation of map activity, set the visibility of components for other activity as View.GONE
3. If you are using Relative layout, tune the layout parameters if needed.

Thats it.. But this is only a workaround that worked for me. If anyone has some better way to do this, please share!!